# I am trying to create a new column to bin values of a time column of a dataframe in python based on time range

Tags: python, pandas

Time column values: 09:11:00,10:11:00...NAT

```
pd.cut(df_master['time_colum`enter code here`n'],bins= 
    ['09:11:00','11:44:00','13:55:00','16:28:00'], labels= 
    ['Morning','Afternoon','Evening'])

TypeError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-102-c66025f961bf> in <module>()
----> 1 pd.cut(df_master['Sent at_time'],bins=['09:11:00','11:44:00','13:55:00','16:28:00'], labels=['Morning','Afternoon','Evening'])

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\tile.py in cut(x, bins, right, labels, retbins, precision, include_lowest, duplicates)
    225         bins = np.asarray(bins)
    226         bins = _convert_bin_to_numeric_type(bins, dtype)
--> 227         if (np.diff(bins) < 0).any():
    228             raise ValueError('bins must increase monotonically.')
    229 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py in diff(a, n, axis)
   1944     op = not_equal if a.dtype == np.bool_ else subtract
   1945     for _ in range(n):
-> 1946         a = op(a[slice1], a[slice2])
   1947 
   1948     return a

TypeError: ufunc 'subtract' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('<U8') dtype('<U8') dtype('<U8')
```

Answer (score 1):

You just have to convert your string time to time delta value

```
    time
0   09:31:00
1   12:04:00
2   14:15:00
3   16:48:00

df1['time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df1['time']
pd.cut(df1['time'],bins=pd.to_timedelta(['09:11:00','11:44:00','13:55:00','16:28:00']), labels=['Morning','Afternoon','Evening'])
```

Out:

```
0      Morning
1    Afternoon
2      Evening
3          NaN
Name: time, dtype: category
```

Comment: Thank you for your response!
But I got a new error:
TypeError: Cannot cast ufunc less input from dtype('<m8[ns]') to dtype('<m8') with casting rule 'same_kind'

Comment: your column should also be a time stamp , use pd.to_timedelta to convert your string column to timedelta